# How to generate binary variable according to the conditions of other variables?

Tags: r, variables, binary, conditional-statements, output

Once again, I apologize for asking this type of question, but the R world is so large that sometime I feel lost, even if I have read some of the best book related with R.
I have the following DB

```
ID=rep((1:3),3)
x<-as.Date("2013-1-1")
y<-as.Date("2013-1-2")
z<-as.Date("2013-1-3")
DATE<-c(x,x,x,y,x,y,z,z,z)
TRAP<-c(1,1,1,3,2,3,2,1,3)
IN<-data.frame(ID,DATE,TRAP)
```

and I would like to produce a binary variable (RESULT) according to the following conditions: if the DATE and the TRAP is the same for the different ID, then RESULT>y otherwise RESULT>n, like this

```
RESULT<-c("y","y","y","y","n","y","n","n","n")
OUT<-cbind(IN,RESULT)
```

I think that the `ifelse` function should be used, but I don't know how to explicit the condition of equality controlling for each ID...
As always, every suggestion is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Sorry, but I can't find the logic behind your `RESULT`...

Comment: Me neither, but this seems to be close: `library(plyr); IN$ID2 <- rep(1:3,each=3); ddply(IN,.(ID2),transform,RESULT=(TRAP==TRAP[1] & DATE==DATE[1]))`

Comment: @juba, ops last y was wrongin the result, so I already edit the result. Basically, if trap and date are the same the result will be y, otherwise n. I hope I am clear enough, sorry for the mistake!

Comment: @Roland, I try your solution but the record number 7 is wrong. I mean it should be FALSE>n instead of TRUE>y

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a way to do it with `plyr` :

```
R> ddply(IN, .(DATE,TRAP), transform, RESULT=ifelse(length(ID)>1,"y","n"))
  ID       DATE TRAP RESULT
1  1 2013-01-01    1      y
2  2 2013-01-01    1      y
3  3 2013-01-01    1      y
4  2 2013-01-01    2      n
5  1 2013-01-02    3      y
6  3 2013-01-02    3      y
7  2 2013-01-03    1      n
8  1 2013-01-03    2      n
9  3 2013-01-03    3      n
```

Note that the rows have been reordered.

---

Another solution with `data.table` :

```
R> DT <- data.table(IN)
R> DT[,RESULT:=ifelse(.N>1,"y","n"), by=list(DATE,TRAP)]
R> DT
   ID       DATE TRAP RESULT
1:  1 2013-01-01    1      y
2:  2 2013-01-01    1      y
3:  3 2013-01-01    1      y
4:  1 2013-01-02    3      y
5:  2 2013-01-01    2      n
6:  3 2013-01-02    3      y
7:  1 2013-01-03    2      n
8:  2 2013-01-03    1      n
9:  3 2013-01-03    3      n
```

There is no reordering here.

---

Or using base `ave`:

```
IN <- within(IN, { RESULT <- ave(TRAP, list(DATE, TRAP), 
               FUN= function(x) ifelse(length(x) > 1, "y", "n"))})
#   ID       DATE TRAP RESULT
# 1  1 2013-01-01    1      y
# 2  2 2013-01-01    1      y
# 3  3 2013-01-01    1      y
# 4  1 2013-01-02    3      y
# 5  2 2013-01-01    2      n
# 6  3 2013-01-02    3      y
# 7  1 2013-01-03    2      n
# 8  2 2013-01-03    1      n
# 9  3 2013-01-03    3      n
```

Comment: Thank you so much @juba for the suggestion. I didn't know the package plyr, really useful! Once again, I appreciate!

Comment: Hi @Arun, I was thinking that ave could be useful for this question (as you already helped me with this function!)...many thanks!

Comment: @Arun thanks for the base solution and the edit. You could have posted antoher answer, because I can't upvote you now :)

Comment: stefano, it's a very handy function that's often undervalued. I'm on a mission to changet that :P. @juba, better to have all in 1 place. You owe me 1 up-vote! :P

Answer (score 1):

You could use `duplicated` for this:

```
IN$RESULT <- ifelse((duplicated(IN[,2:3])+duplicated(IN[,2:3],fromLast=TRUE))>0,
                       "y","n")

#   ID       DATE TRAP RESULT
# 1  1 2013-01-01    1      y
# 2  2 2013-01-01    1      y
# 3  3 2013-01-01    1      y
# 4  1 2013-01-02    3      y
# 5  2 2013-01-01    2      n
# 6  3 2013-01-02    3      y
# 7  1 2013-01-03    2      n
# 8  2 2013-01-03    1      n
# 9  3 2013-01-03    3      n
```

Comment: good to know this other useful function!I appreciate your help.